# R package odbc 1.4.1 Error. Unable to prepare query with "?"

Tags: r, odbc, r-package, r-dbi

Starting from version odbc 1.4, unable to prepare sql queries with "?" parameters. It worked in versions 1.3.5 and older.

What has changed in odbc?

```
Example for FirebirdSQL:

> packageVersion("odbc")
[1] ‘1.3.5’
> prepare <- dbSendQuery(conn, "select * from sec$users where sec$user_name = ?")
> prepare
<OdbcResult>
  SQL  select * from sec$users where sec$user_name = ?
  ROWS Fetched: 0 [complete]
       Changed: 0
```

```
> packageVersion("odbc")
[1] ‘1.4.1’
> prepare <- dbSendQuery(conn, "select * from sec$users where sec$user_name = ?")
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1710: 07002
[ODBC Firebird Driver]COUNT field incorrect
```

Comment: Posted at https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/726 too.

Comment: I don't use firebird, but from https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-appx06-userattr.html I'm wondering if your query should instead be `"select U.* from sec$users U where U.sec$user_name = ?"`. (I could easily be wrong.)